# Webstorm code completion does not show bootstrap classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webstorm, code-completion

What do I have to change in my webstorm IDE that the bootstrap classes are recognized when I do:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" />
```

At the moment I have always to re-check the class names by looking into the bootstrap css files. Thats not so nice...

Comment: It should be automatically finding the classes for you as you type them out... Assuming you aren't copying/pasting you should be able to have webstorm give you a quick look of available classes.

Comment: @Pascal have you solved this issue ? i can't get the classes in Bootstrap to auto complete either.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Make sure it is turned on. Do the following in WebStorm:

```
File | Settings | IDE Settings | Editor - Code Completion
```

Or:

```
File | Settings | Type in the search bar "code completion"
```

The second option will take you straight to the code completion options if in some case you could not find it via the first way.

More information can be found [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html)

Comment: add auto-complete settings are on.. but webstorm still not suggesting for bootstrap classes.. but only for normal html tags.. any idea ?

Comment: Are you referencing your Bootstrap files correctly?

Comment: means? may you please elaborate.. how to refer bootstrap files?

Comment: This is not ideal. If you are dealing with an html fragment ( think react of angular ) the IDE won't know you are trying to reference a bootstrap class, because you haven't explicitly included it in your fragment.

Comment: I actually think that Jenny's answer should be marked as correct because this is an issue where the files were not locally accessible.

Comment: The answer by @rajesh-meena - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346665/1006651 solves the problem

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem and finally fixed it!!
**You need to download the Bootstrap library LOCALLY.**

This worked:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
```

But this didn't work:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Cheers,
JJ

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos There is an feature request regarding this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31724

Answer (score 4):

For a quick-fix, downloading the `bootstrap.min.css` or whichever you are using locally, and then referencing it like

```
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

solves the problem.

I think another way for WebStorm to be able to autocomplete without referring to it locally would be to add the file as an external library

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the solution:

- Right click on style folder
- Mark  directory as test sources root

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem is the way i referenced the css files.

My file structure :

```
Project
   /App 
      -index.html
   /bower_components
       /bootstrap
          /dist 
             /css 
               -bootstrap.css
```

and i referenced them like so :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootswatch/superhero/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

The css was applied but no intellisence was provided. 
I think the css was applied due to my .bowerrc file.

```
 {
   "directory": "bower_components"
 }
```

I changed the path to the relative one and webstorm recognized my bootstrap classes.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootswatch/superhero/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: by doing this you "fixed" code completion, but you broke grunt build. grunt looks for vendor css and js files in `bower_components` folder (*not* `..\bower_components`). I read that WS 11 has a better integration with yeoman, and this problem is fixed. Don't know if it is fixable in WS10, however

Comment: @Felix I'm new to grunt .. can you elaborate on "you broke the grunt build". 
To my understanding Grunt will still find them under the root folder in bower_components this is just a reference from index. It does not relay on how i referenced them from my index.html for the build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using style tag in your `PHP` page, it prevents loading `CSS` class code completion.
Put your styles into `CSS` file then load it and remove style tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had to mark my styles directory, which contains my css, as "Resources" in module settings. I also had to mark my bower components and node module directories as "Sources".

Answer (score 0):

To add stylesheets to your global JS libraries:

1. Open the IDE Preferences menu and go to Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries
2. Select the library you wish to add a stylesheet to and click Edit... on the right-hand side
3. Click the `+` button just above Documentation URLs and select Attach Files...
4. Find and select the stylesheet you wish to add, then click OK to close the Edit Library dialogue window

The stylesheet is now attached to the global JS library, so you will get CSS code completions/recommendations from the stylesheet whenever you include the JS library for a project in the IDE.